# What potential security issues running sandboxd as root?

Tags: macos, sandbox, privilege-escalation

I have noticed that MacOS is running its sandbox process under the root user. This implies that any sandboxed process, assuming that it can escape the sandbox, would then have root privileges. Am I wrong in assuming this?

Comment: This depends entirely on how `sandboxd` manages sandboxing. It very well many be running privileged only so it can set up a sandboxing context, in which case a sandbox escape would not lead to privilege escalation. If, on the other hand, it works like firejail (ew) where a setuid wrapper attempts to provide security, an escape _would_ lead to getting root.